# swarm and multiple composer rest server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I successfully implementend a docker swarm network on two different host that is working perfectly.

I can successfully created a composer rest server with the Admin card from Org1 BUT if I used the Admin card from Org2 (tested on host 1 & 2 with modified IP in connection.json) I can only see

**"System : General business network methods".**

Any idea what could cause that ? thanks a lot.

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: After updating couchdb image from 0.4.6 to 0.4.8 I did not have this problem anymore.